# Attach an image to the top of the page, no scroll for img, in the body element

Tags: css, background, background-attachment, background-size

I have the following problem. I think, there is a quick way to do it, but right now I cannot find the way to solve it.

So, I have an image and I want it to be as a background image **ONLY** on the top of the page in the `<body>` element. Currently it is moving to the bottom of the page if I scroll down.

**I have the folllowing code:**

```
body {
    color: #d0d0d0;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5; 
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background:url(../img/main-bg-top.png) no-repeat top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could create another class and insert it before of all your content, something like this: **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbefo4os/)**

```
body {
    color: #d0d0d0;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 400; 
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5; 
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background:#000;
}
.top-image{height:0;}
.top-image img{max-width: 100%;}
.container{height:900px; }
```

html:

```
<div class="top-image">
    <img src="http://www.wormzweb.com/images/photoalbum/album_28/nature_2118.jpg">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>random text.</p>
</div>
```

This was a quick sketch, workaround with the best way for you and the proper way to write this code if you wanna.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for some reason. Let me try your method.

Comment: You're welcome bro ;) pls consider marking my answer as correct.